# Add conda environment info to terminal prompt

Tags: bash, virtualenv, conda

(I'm using anaconda on a MacBook)
By default conda adds the environment info to the comand prompt as follows:

```
$ source activate my_env

(my_env) $ source deactivate

$
```

This can be switched off and on using

```
conda config --set changeps1 (true|false)
```

Since my terminal prompt is already customised I'd like to add the env info in a different way, but don't know how to exactly.

Right now I'm using the two commands `sac`and `dac` in my .bash_profile file to activate and deactivate envs and therefore did this amateurish attempt adding `env_var`:

```
env_var=""

#activate env (default env = my_env)
sac() {

    if [ -z $1 ];
    then
        ENV="my_env"
    else
        ENV="${1}"
    fi

    source activate ${ENV}

    env_var="${ENV}"
}

#deactivate env
dac() {
    source deactivate
    env_var=""
}

env_info() {
    if [[ ${env_var} == "" ]]
    then
        echo ""
    else
        echo "in ${env_var}"
    fi
}

PS1="\u "
PS1+="$(env_info) \$";
```

Which is not working (my bash knowledge is only rudimentary sorry...).
`env_info` always stays `""` no matter wether I call `sac`or `dac`in the terminal or not.

**Question1:** Why is the code not working?

**Question2:** Or is there maybe another way to get the current env-info in a - for this purpose - useful format?
`conda info --envs` returns to much info...

Comment: See here for how I did it: https://github.com/bryanwweber/dot-files/blob/master/macos.bash_profile#L16 The environment variable you're looking for is `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method suggested in the comment from **darthbith** works very well. The variable `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` is exactly what I was looking for:

```
>>> source activate myEnv

>>> echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
myEnv
```

Answer (score 8):

To add to the answer by **A.Wenn**, this is what I added to my custom prompt

```
PS1=""

# Add conda environment to prompt
if [ ! -z "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV" ]
then
    PS1+="($CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) "
fi
```